# Property Metadata Binding Assertion Failed

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, property-binding

I have a View in my SAPUI5 application where I am creating a OData Model.

In the next step I want to use his metadata to bind a Property.

My error message is
abap.js:64 Assertion failed: COLUMN/@sap:label is not a valid property path

I think here is another mistake because before i tried this, I had always a OData Model which i defined in the manifest file and it worked fine - but now when creating a Model in the same view it doesn't work.

I also thougt about to set the Model to the View, but I think its not neccessery because in the Path I am saying, please look at "oModel" OData Model for your data. {oModel</....

Did I forgot something?

```
        // creating model
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/xxxx/", "oModel");
                                

                    var oLabel = new sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartLabel({                            
                        text: "{oModel>/#showcase/" + column + "/@sap:label}" // {ODataModel>/#showcase/" + column + "/@sap:label}" // 
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the "oModel" inside the line

```
text: "{oModel>/#showcase/" + column + "/@sap:label}"
```

refers to a name, under which you can assign the model to any Control that is inherited from `sap.ui.base.ManagedObject`. it has no relationship to the variable name "oModel" that you use to create the model in JS.

the following should work (note, I replaced one occurrence of `oModel` with `bla`, the other with `blubber` to point out the difference

```
var bla = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/xxxx/");
                          
var oLabel = new sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartLabel({                            
    text: "{blubber>/#showcase/" + column + "/@sap:label}" 
});

oLabel.setModel(bla, "blubber")
```

or, alternatively:

```
var oLabel = new sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartLabel({
    models: {
        "blubber": new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/xxxx/")
    },                            
    text: "{blubber>/#showcase/" + column + "/@sap:label}" 
});
```